How to create a looparrow with tikz-cd?
I'm drawing a commutative diagram in latex and I want one of the maps to signify an immersion, which is denoted by a looparrow in my context, but I can't seem to find how to do it with tikz.
I mean something similar to \looparrowright in a standard math environment. Any ideas how to do this? I tried to find an example in tikz documentation but I didn't seem to find it.
My current diagram is
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A <right loop arrow goes here>{r}{f}\arrow{d}{p} & B \arrow{d}{l} \\
    C\arrow{r}{g} & D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to a compilable one. Starting with \documentclass ending with \end{document}?

@AlainRemillard thanks

Since this is really a question about commutative diagrams, not TikZ in general, you might want to change the title of your question to "How to create a looparrow with tikz-cd?"

You can use Glyph to define an arrow tip. Since you want an arrow tail, use looparrowleft and swap.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amssymb}

\tikzset{
  immersion/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft, swap]}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A\arrow[r, immersion->, "f"]\arrow[d,"p"] & B \arrow[d,"l"] \\
  C\arrow[r,"g"] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


+1: It's amazing on how customizable this is!
